# Elavon Payment Method For Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

I would like to add a payment method for Magento 1.9 called Elavon. Elavon is a credit card processing feature/company that we are required to use. (this is Elavon's website: https://www.elavon.ca/). However unfortunately, Magento does not come with an Elavon Payment Method by default. I was looking at this before which is a Magento Elavon Extension: https://www.rootways.com/shop/magento-elavon-payment-module-extension however this Magento extension costs a high amount of money, and there is absolutely no way to get this Magento extension for free if at all possible. We are out of luck, because we cannot use the one that comes with Magento by default at all which is: Authorize.net.

Is there an alternative way on how to add the Elavon payment method to Magento? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

First up, I'm not familiar with Elavon and I'm going to assume they don't provide an extension themselves. It's something most payment providers do as it helps to make their integrations easier.

That said, if they don't have one freely available, you can:

- build an extension yourself;
- pay for someone's time by buying an existing extension;
- or pay for someone to build one.

From looking at it, the link you shared comes down to an extension that costs $99, from experience, developing a payment module will pretty much always end up costing (way) more than that.

*If the point is creditcard processing, I'm confident there's alternative payment providers out there though, I would argue that if the costs are a problem maybe a different provider might be more suitable.*